# Ice Cream Sandwich(Api14) android users keeps reporting StackOverflowError error

Tags: android, android-layout, stack-overflow, android-recyclerview

Certain 4.0.1-4.0.2 users keep reporting this StackOverflowError error in my application in my Google Play developer account, how can I decide which Fragment/layout is causing the problem?? I have been trying to fix it for a week now but still no luck

```
at android.graphics.Paint.getTextRunAdvances(Paint.java:1691)
at android.text.TextLine.handleText(TextLine.java:745)
at android.text.TextLine.handleRun(TextLine.java:972)
at android.text.TextLine.drawRun(TextLine.java:397)
at android.text.TextLine.draw(TextLine.java:199)
at android.text.Layout.draw(Layout.java:425)
at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:5241)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11118)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10557)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2856)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10555)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2856)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11121)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10557)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2856)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11121)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10557)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2856)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11121)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10557)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2856)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10555)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2856)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10555)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2856)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11121)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10557)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2856)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10555)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2856)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10555)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2856)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.drawChild(Unknown Source)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11121)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.draw(Unknown Source)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10557)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2856)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2502)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11121)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10557)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2856)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10555)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2856)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11121)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.draw(Unknown Source)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10557)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2856)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10555)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2856)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11121)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10557)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2856)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10555)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2856)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild(Unknown Source)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10555)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2856)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11121)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10557)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2856)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10555)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2856)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10555)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2856)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10555)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2856)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11121)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2290)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10557)
at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:840)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2049)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1773)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2585)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: which application is it? can you provide playstore link to download it?

Comment: @Yogesh Here you go https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.redeagle07.egyptianleague it's a sports application, you can switch it to English from the last item in the navigation drawer

Comment: @RedEagle - Did you find any solution ?